# Custom $wpdb returns unexpected time based results

Tags: wpdb, sql

I am using the $wpdb class to do a custom SQL query but I am getting weird results. 
Basically this is what my SQL query is supposed to do

1. Retrieve the titles of post_types 'question' only if they are
2. published within the last 7 days
3. have a taxonomy of 'question_tag'
4. have the terms 'another-sample' or 'sample'

The problem is the number 2. The query seems to be returning questions that are dated later than 7 days. To illustrate this I am also retrieving the post_date. As you can see in the below result set. the question titled 'lkddfs' is more than 7 days old. Help?

```
function rs_send_email_to_interested_users() {
    global $wpdb;
    $wpdb->show_errors();
    $sql ="SELECT DISTINCT $wpdb->posts.post_title,  $wpdb->posts.post_date FROM $wpdb->posts
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_relationships ON ($wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id)
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->term_taxonomy ON ($wpdb->term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = $wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_taxonomy_id)
    INNER JOIN $wpdb->terms ON ($wpdb->term_taxonomy.term_id = $wpdb->terms.term_id)
    WHERE 1=1 AND
    $wpdb->term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'question_tag' AND
    $wpdb->posts.post_type = 'question' AND
    $wpdb->posts.post_status = 'publish' AND
    $wpdb->terms.slug = 'another-sample' OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'sample' AND
    //the date logic doesn't seem to qork quite right
    $wpdb->posts.post_date > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
    $question_titles = $wpdb->get_results( $sql, ARRAY_N );
    return $question_titles;
}
```

And here is my result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (   
            [0] => lkddfs
            [1] => 2013-03-03 03:05:57 // This question is more than 7 days old!
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Good tactical games
            [1] => 2013-03-24 04:48:04
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => my recent question
            [1] => 2013-03-24 14:58:25
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => romans question
            [1] => 2013-03-26 21:18:00
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This *may* be your problem:

```
$wpdb->terms.slug = 'another-sample' OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'sample' AND
//the date logic doesn't seem to qork quite right
$wpdb->posts.post_date > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
```

Your OR operator might be confusing the query. Try using parentheses:

```
($wpdb->terms.slug = 'another-sample' OR $wpdb->terms.slug = 'sample') AND
//the date logic doesn't seem to qork quite right
$wpdb->posts.post_date > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY)";
```